# directx 2 mesh rotating but 1. model will turn y , 2. model turn z axis.(i am trying to make turn different way)

Tags: model, rotation, directx

directx 2 mesh rotating but 1. model will turn y , 2. model turn z axis.(i am trying to make turn different way)

```
    static float index = 0.0f; index+=0.003f;  
    D3DXMATRIX matRotate; //rotate matrix
    D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&matRotate, index, 0, 0); // set up matrix
    directx->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matRotate);
```

but this rotate 2 off them same way

Comment: Be a bit more specific, what is going wrong. You have two meshes. Ok. They shall rotate. Ok. But which object shall rotate about which axis? What is the actual result and why is it errornous? Furthermore, provide the drawing code for the two meshes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :).My problem is " I have 2 meshs in screen.2 meshs are on (0,0,0) cordinats.How can i put 1. mesh to (10,1,1) and rotate it, 2.mesh to (-10,-2,0). ? (i am making game engine and i want put models in diffrenet cordinates. but both of them turn same way)

Comment: Then the world matrix of the first mesh is `Rotation * Translation(10,1,1)` and for the second mesh it is `Translation(-10,-2,0)`

Comment: but how? it turns world not mesh.How can i turn mesh?

Comment: if You can look to "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19705946/projem/deneme.rar" (and press w a s d) plane and gun turn same way.
Edit : You must have directx sdk to open tihs you know :D

Comment: Transforming a mesh works with setting the world transform and drawing the mesh. If the next mesh needs a different transform, then you can set a different world transform and draw the next mesh. Btw I cannot open the program.

Comment: thanks :) its works :) if you summit answer i will +1 it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meshes are affected by the world matrix (+view +projection). If you want to transform meshes independently, you will have to apply the according world matrix and draw the mesh. So:

```
Apply world matrix 1
Draw mesh 1
Apply world matrix 2
Draw mesh 2
```

Comment: sorry i cant +1 it it says you need 15 reputation but i accept it :)